# OpenApi 3.0 shows all af the HTTP methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

My OpenApi gone crazy... i created 2 simple rest APIs

```
    @RequestMapping("/inWithHibernate")
    @PutMapping
    public void inDbMobile() {
        hibernateInsert.inDB();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/outWithHibernate")
    @GetMapping
    public MobileEntity outDbMobile(@RequestParam(name = "id")Long id) {
        return hibernateInsert.fromDB(id);
    }
```

as i understand it it should show one Put method and one Get method...Instead of that is shows all of the methods, can you please explain what is happening ?

my dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image: OpenApi3.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@RequestMapping` tells Spring that any HTTP request with the specified path should be mapped to the corresponding method. The path should be specified as an argument of the `@PutMapping` and `@GetMapping` annotations and the `@RequestMapping` annotation should be removed.